# Mongoose UPDATE function not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on the user accounts part of my project. I successfully completed the the GET, POST and DELETE methods, now I am missing the PUT.

When the user submits the update user form, the `req.body` will be something like this

```
{ user:
   { firstName: 'asas',
     lastName: 'assa',
     studentId: '1234',
     email: 'as@as.as',
     password: '123' 
    }
}
```

My schema looks like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  cuid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  firstName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  lastName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  studentId: { type: 'Number', required: true },
  password: { type: 'String', required: true },
  email: { type: 'String', required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
  lastLogin: { type: 'Date', default: null, required: false },
});
```

and finally my update function looks like this.

```
export function updateUser(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body)
  firstName = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.firstName );
  lastName = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.lastName);
  studentId = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.studentId);
  email = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.email);
  password = sha512(req.body.user.password).toString('hex');

  let update = { firstName, lastName, studentId, email, password };

  User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.cuid,update,function(err,updated){
    if(error){
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }else{
      return res.json({ user: updated });
    }
  });
}
```

I can't figure out why my put method is not working, maybe a second pair of eyes can see the flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The problem is that you aren't passing the id properly. MongoDB is looking for an identifier in the form of an object. You've written:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.cuid,update,function(err,updated){
```

What you need to do is separate your arguments into separate objects:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.cuid }, { $set: update }, function(err, updated) {
```

Additionally, you need to use `$set`, otherwise you'll overwrite the whole Object. `$set` tells Mongo to only update the fields specified via the `update` object, which you defined a couple lines above.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the correct structure of findOneAndUpdate. first you have define , on which basis search the id.

```
export function updateUser(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body)
  firstName = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.firstName );
  lastName = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.lastName);
  studentId = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.studentId);
  email = sanitizeHtml(req.body.user.email);
  password = sha512(req.body.user.password).toString('hex');

  let update = { firstName, lastName, studentId, email, password };

 User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.cuid}, {$set: updated}, function (err, user) {//correct structure
    if(error){
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }else{
      return res.json({ user: updated });
    }
  });
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make the update parameter as an object.

The first parameter is a query object. For example {firstName : "whatever"}.
The second parameter contains the updates.

As an example, if you are trying to update an user last name, and searching it by the name, you should have something like

```
findOneAndUpdate({firstName:req.body.firstName},{lastName:req.body.lastName},function...})
```

I believe you are trying to search by the id, so you should put something like

```
findOneAndUpdate({cuid:req.body.cuid},{$set:{firstName:req.body.firstName,studentId:req.body.studentId...}),function...})
```

I hope my answer was helpful for you.